# Spring Kafka Prevent Duplicate Reads

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I use spring kafka 2.x to read messages from kafka.

My problem is if my method spent a time in my kafkalistener method,that time kafka send same message twice and that is problem for me.What I want if I read message from kafka that time kafka doesnt send me this message second time values like max.poll.interval.ms not quarantee to read message at once.What is the right way to achive read at once strategy in spring boot.In my message I dont have a key for that reason I cant put a control.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "mytopics",groupId = "mygroup",concurrency = 3",containerFactory = "MyListenerContainerFactory")
void messageReceiver(@Payload String data, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) {

  String receivedTopic=  headers.get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC).toString();

        //DO something
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the results of the poll within `max.poll.interval.ms`. So increase it, or reduce `max.poll.records`.

Kafka has no mechanism to prevent redelivery if you take too long to process.

Comment: hi gary thank for your reply,https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-exactly-once ı read some article about but I am little bit confused are you sure?

Comment: This is a common confusion. `"Exactly Once"` with Kafka applies to a complete `read->process->write` sequence, when the `read` and `write` are both Kafka. The guarantee is that the **complete sequence** will only be processed once. If the `process` or `write` steps fail, the `read` and `process` will be repeated (at least once).

Comment: what is the key point?Also I write kafka at any time and I want to read this message only once?is this means(Exactly Once) a method which read a topic and write another topic at same transaction?

Comment: Yes, that is the only meaning of exactly once in Kafka. The complete sequence will be executed exactly one time, but the read/process part can be retried.

Comment: I guess your application needs to deal with delivery of duplicates, e.g. by keeping track of received messageIds and withdrawing incoming duplicates of in-process messages, see https://chrisrichardson.net/post/microservices/patterns/2020/10/16/idempotent-consumer.html

Comment: If there is no inherent message id in the data, you can use a combination of `group/partition/offset` as a "key" to use as a message id, to detect duplicates.